# Reuse an open EntityConnection used by previously ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.1 in a web application and i'm using the UnitOfWork pattern. I open a new `ObjectContext` by each request and it's used for all operations in the current request. I also open and close an `EntityConnection` manually.

It would be better if I would not close the `EntityConnection` and reuse it for future request. I know that it is a Connection Pool mechanism and my ask is:

Have EF this feature included?
and if not
Can I use an open EntityConnection (Used from previously `ObjectContext`) in another `ObjectContext`?

The Connection String is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do that. Connection pooling is pretty fast. Just take a new connection.